# Symmetric Random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, {\mathcal A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable in $\Omega$. $X$ is said to be ${\mathbf symmetric}$ (about $0$) if $X$ and $-X$ are equal in law. I want to show that the following are equivalent:
(i) $X$ is symmetric
(ii) $X^+$ and $X^-$ are equal in law (where $X^+=\max\{X,0\}$ and $X^-=\max\{-X,0\}$).

(i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) is obvious since the function $x\to \max\{x,0\}$ is Borel. I need some help with the opposite direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume (ii) holds. Let $u$ denote any (bounded) measurable function and $Y$ any random variable distributed like $X^+$ or $X^-$, then
$$
\mathbb E(u(X))=u(0)\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb E(u(X^+);X^+\gt0)+\mathbb E(u(-X^-);X^-\gt0),
$$
hence
$$
\mathbb E(u(X))=u(0)\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb E(u(Y)+u(-Y);Y\gt0).
$$
The RHS stays the same when one replaces $u$ by $x\mapsto u(-x)$ hence $X$ and $-X$ coincide in distribution.